# Very hard probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

One of the first 6 positive integers is to be chosen by casting an unbiased die. Let this random experiment be repeated five independent times. Let $X_1$ be the random variable representing the number of terminations in the set $\{x, x = 1,2,3\}$ and $X_2$ be that of those in the set $\{x, x=4,5\}$ (so for example: if the outcome is $\{3,2,5,6,6\}$ then $X_1 = 2$ and $X_2 = 1$). What is $Pr \left[ X_1 = 2, X_2 = 1 \right]$. I don't know what to do. How should I think about this problem?

Comment: if it helps: the answer key gives $5/72$.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "termination" is.  Suppose my 5 tosses come to $\{3,1,3,6,3\}$.  What are $X_1$ and $X_2$ in that case?

Comment: What do you mean by termination? Do you mean that the last roll gives $1,2, or 3$ or $4, or 5$?

Comment: @lulu they're $X_1 = 4$ and $X_2 = 0$.. $X_1$ represents the number of times one of the numbers in the first set appears

Comment: Ok, thanks.  You might want to edit the question...I think others will be confused by the wording.

Comment: but I don't know for sure. let's assume this is what it means

Comment: What is asked is a conditional probability?

Comment: @Bernard no what's asked is the probability that both happen

Comment: why did I get a -1?

Comment: @George care about the downvote. Often the downvotes are not compehensible. I made an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wonder: what is the probability that the first two end up in set $\{1,2,3\}$, then the third ends up in $\{4,5\}$ and then the last two in $\{6\}$? The answer is: $$\left(\frac36\right)^2\times\frac26\times\left(\frac16\right)^2$$

Now wonder: how many different orders are there for this? The answer is: $$\frac{5!}{2!1!2!}$$

For each of these orders the probability that the event occurs is the same, so adding up these probabilities results in multiplication of both factors and gives the final answer:

$$\frac{5!}{2!1!2!}\left(\frac36\right)^2\times\frac26\times\left(\frac16\right)^2$$

You are dealing with [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Comment: In general if I want to find the number of ways $k$ items can be chosen out of $n$ items, with each of the $k$ items containing $r_k$ items, I divide $n!$ by $\prod_{t=1}^k r_t!$?

Comment: Yes. You actually start with all $n!$ permutations and then you realize that every (distinghuishable) possibility is counted $r_1!\times\cdots\times r_k!$ times. To 'repair' and find the real number of possibilities you must divide by that factor.